MultiThreading or Parallel Running of API Calls in ASP.NET MVC C#
I'm currently working with an ASP.NET MVC application that interacts with over 10 suppliers' APIs to gather data. Our current approach involves waiting for all API calls to complete using Task.WaitAll, but this leads to poor user experience due to connection timeouts. How can we enhance performance in our ASP.NET MVC application to mitigate these timeouts and improve user experience?
I've attempted to optimize my ASP.NET MVC application by using Task.WhenAny among other approaches to handle multiple API calls asynchronously. Despite these efforts, I'm encountering persistent errors. The view is displaying no values, and errors seem to be slipping through without being caught. Additionally, the controller is passing these errors to the view. How can I resolve these issues and ensure smoother performance?
So Please let me know if there is a any approach to improve the code.
Example Code below :
 public List<string> ApplySources(List<string> sources, string suppliers, List<RNR> lstRnr, FlightSearchRequest rq, Client client,
            List<FlightDetail> lstflightdetails, List<PccMatrix> pccMatrixList, bool isdomesticreturn = false)
        {
            List<string> lstsources = new List<string>();
            SortedDictionary<string, Airport> airports = _flyCache.Airports;
            List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
            List<FlightDetail> flightDetails = new List<FlightDetail>();
            FlightSearchRequest copyRequest = (FlightSearchRequest)FLY.Helper.Helper.DeepCloneusingJson(rq);
            FLY.dal.Flight.Handlers.NearbyAirportsHandler nearbyAirportsHandler = new dal.Flight.Handlers.NearbyAirportsHandler();
            List<entities.Flight.NearbyAirports> nearbyAirports = nearbyAirportsHandler.GetNearbyAirportsActive();
            List<entities.Flight.NearbyAirports> filterednearbyairports = null;
            string[] flyapisources = new string[] { "FHIN", "FHBD", "FHAE", "FHTR", "FHMY", "FHSG" };
            int loopindex = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < sources.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rq.AirTravelPreference.AirlinePreference)
                    && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(copyRequest.AirTravelPreference.AirlinePreference))
                    copyRequest.AirTravelPreference.AirlinePreference = "";
                IFlightsSuppliers supplier = null;
                if (!rq.IsBSAdvancedSearch)
                {
                    if (sources[i] == "MY" && suppliers.Contains("MY"))
                    {
                        List<RNR> lstRNRsource = lstRnr.Where(a => a.Source == "ALL" || a.Source == "MY").ToList();
                        if (RNRToAllowSearch(lstRNRsource, airports, copyRequest))
                            supplier = new MyFares.Mystifly();
                    }
                    if (sources[i] == "2S" && suppliers.Contains("2S"))
                    {
                        List<RNR> lstRNRsource = lstRnr.Where(a => a.Source == "ALL" || a.Source == "2S").ToList();
                        if (RNRToAllowSearch(lstRNRsource, airports, copyRequest))
                            supplier = new SabreRest.Flights();
                    }
                    if (sources[i] == "1S" && suppliers.Contains("1S"))
                    {
                        List<RNR> lstRNRsource = lstRnr.Where(a => a.Source == "ALL" || a.Source == "1S").ToList();
                        if (RNRToAllowSearch(lstRNRsource, airports, copyRequest, pccMatrixList))
                        {
                            if (nearbyAirports != null)
                                filterednearbyairports = nearbyAirports.Where(a => a.Source.Equals("1S")).ToList();
                            supplier = new Sabre.SabreAPI();
                        }
                    }
                    //Singapore
                    if (sources[i] == "SQ" && suppliers.Contains("SQ"))
                    {
                        List<RNR> lstRNRsource = lstRnr.Where(a => a.Source == "ALL" || a.Source == "SQ").ToList();
                        if (RNRToAllowSearch(lstRNRsource, airports, copyRequest) && (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(copyRequest.AirTravelPreference.AirlinePreference)
                            || (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(copyRequest.AirTravelPreference.AirlinePreference)
                            && copyRequest.AirTravelPreference.AirlinePreference.ToUpper().Split(',').Contains("SQ"))))
                            supplier = new SingaporeAirline.SingaporeAirlineAPI();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                }
                if (supplier != null)
                {
                    lstsources.Add(sources[i]);
                    var newpccMatrixList = pccMatrixList.Where(a => a.IsAvailable).ToList();
                    if (sources[i].StartsWith("FH"))
                    {
                        newpccMatrixList = newpccMatrixList.Where(a => a.Pcc == sources[i]).ToList();
                    }
                    List<entities.Flight.NearbyAirports> copiednearbyairports = null;
                    if (filterednearbyairports != null)
                        copiednearbyairports = FLY.Helper.Helper.DeepCloneusingJson(filterednearbyairports);
                    Task myTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        supplier.Search(copyRequest, flightDetails, newpccMatrixList, client, copiednearbyairports);
                    });
                    taskList.Add(myTask);
                    pccMatrixList.ForEach(a => a.IsAvailable = false);
                }
            }
            try
            {
                if (taskList.Count != 0)
                    Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());//Value is 40. if its any other value need to set 40 again.
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
            {
                Task tsk = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    log.Error("ApplySources/FlightCore : " + ex.StackTrace + ex.Message);
                });
            }
            if (flightDetails.Count == 0)
                return lstsources;
            if (!iscouponexecuted)
                flightBookingCouponDetails = new FlightBookCouponCodeProvider().GetBookingCoupons(copyRequest, airports);
            var currentrequest = FLY.Helper.Helper.DeepCloneusingJson(copyRequest);
            flightDetails.ForEach(a => { a.FlightSearchRequest = currentrequest; a.BookingCouponDetails = flightBookingCouponDetails; });
            return lstsources;
        }


Task.Factory.StartNew is outdated. Use Task.Run instead.

Your if statements are just repeated. Can you post real code?

Yes, I purposely added this as, we will be getting different supplier Details as below
if (sources[i] == "MY" && suppliers.Contains("MY"))
{
supplier = new SabreRest.Flights();
}
if (sources[i] == "MY1" && suppliers.Contains("MY1"))
{
supplier = new SabreRest1.Flights();
}

Please Consider below variables are different suppliers

Then please post real code so that we can give you the best possible answer. Don't make us guess what you're intending to do.

@Enigmativity , I have updated with original code

As one OTA developer to another, don't do this. Use true asynchronous methods, HttpClient through HttpClientFactory and avoid blocking threads as far as possible. NEVER use Task.Run for remote service calls. Air ticket searches take several seconds to complete and your thread will spinwait while waiting for them, preventing your app from serving more searches. And simplify your code. Break it into separate methods that do one thing at a time. Creating a request is complex, processing the response is complex. Don't put everything in one long method

DeepCloneusingJson absolutely not. It's not just that RAM is at a premium (A response can be 1-2MB) but this generates a lot of large temporary strings that need to be garbage collected. Your server will freeze very quickly as the GC runs to clean up all those temporary strings and buffers that are no longer needed. When you need buffers you should try to use reusable buffers through eg ArrayPool as much as possible. Read Memory management and garbage collection (GC) in ASP.NET Core

Your code is a bundle of cyclomatic complexity. You really need to break that code down into clearer re-usable chunks.

Also .Helper.Helper looks like illegal C# code. Is this your actual real code? Can you provide a [mcve]?

If you control the APIs that you call, then make them faster or more reliable. If you don't control them, then you need to consider what to do if one or more of them fails or times out.
If the main UX problem is that it takes too long before a request times out, then decrease the timeout. If, rather, you can live with a longer wait time, but want to prevent errors, you can increase the timeout. In the latter case, however, it's probably a good idea to add some sort of work-in-progress indicator to the user interface.
If you can live with getting only some of the API responses, you may aim for some more sophisticated synchronization mechanisms. In the extreme, Task.WhenAny just waits for the first task to complete, so that allows all other tasks to fail. Is that what you want?
The way this kind of issue is usually handled is with Composite UIs, where the UI (rather than the server) makes n concurrent requests, and asynchronously fills in each of the UI elements as responses arrive.

In the extreme, Task.WhenAny just waits for the first task to complete, so that allows all other tasks to fail. Is that what you want? --> No

My requirement is right now we are calling multiple suppliers api and adding it into the task list and then executing, but some time some server may return the result late thus our server request time is getting timed out. So we want to implement where if any suppliers data is available that bind first then later we can bind other suppliers details

Let me guess - NDC. Just don't use such code, use HttpClient, asynchronous methods and make absolutely sure you use HttpClientFactory and never start threads. You have a lot of concurrent requests, air ticket searches take a long time (seconds) as far as CPUs are concerned and blocking operations actually start with spinwaits. If you start 8 concurrent searches on an 8-core machine you'll block all 8 cores for several seconds while waiting for responses.

@MarkSeeman this is a very specific, Eirik-scale kind of problem. Sabre is a GDS, an air ticket search and booking aggregator. Travel agencies used to search and book tickets using the APIs of those aggregators. In the past there were a handful of large GDSs like Amadeus, Sabre. Lately airlines tried to get rid of the middlemen, forcing travel agencies to talk to every single one of them using the NDC "standard". But since airlines aren't software houses all implementations are somewhat different and ... many airlines went to the GDSs for implementations

@MarkSeeman a search request can be hundreds of KBs, including not just your dates and airports but specific configurations and restrictions sent by the agent. The responses for the 50 flights you see can be 1-2MB long, containing all details for fees, taxes, fare rules, timezones and a lot more. You really really need pipelines, async operations, throttling, SAX-like parsing. And the GC costs are measured in servers, not seconds

If you are going to get into your API a search request and then it is up to you call dozens of other APIs and aggregate all of these informations and some of your calls or the aggregation itself can take a lot of time, you have to decouple the incoming request and returning the data.
Normally in such cases your api takes the incoming request and generates a background job with a unique id and then returns this unique id. With another API request against your server and the given id the frontend can ask about the state of this job and get the data when it is ready.
In ASP core you normally use a library like Hangfire or Quartz.Net for these kind of background jobs and I would highly recommended this to you. This is not a trivial task to do, but there is no simple code snippet you could throw on your code to make it magically faster. You just have to deal with this long running processes and this means decouple the search request from giving the answer.
